# SQL Server : can't concatenate string in the middle of other strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server stored procedures I want to do this:

```
"hello xxx how are you"
```

where `xxx` is a value of a variable

I tried this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertToPinTable
    (@callerID VARCHAR (200),  
     @vAccount VARCHAR (200))
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @textEnglish VARCHAR
     textEnglish = CONCAT ( "hello", @vAccount)

     INSERT INTO pinData([CallerID], [body], [processed]) 
     VALUES (@callerID, @textEnglish, 0)
END
```

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'textEnglish'

it seems that using `CONCAT` is not correct, could you help me please

(if I can insert the value of vAccount to the `hello` word, then in the same way I can insert the value of textEnglish, to the string `how are you`)

Comment: what do you mean by `using CONCAT is not correct`?

Comment: @vkp i received this error Incorrect syntax near 'textEnglish'. that's why i though concat is not correct

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise you end up with a string of **1 character length** - usually *not* what you want!

Comment: To set a variable you'd use `SET @variableName` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE insertToPinTable
(
@callerID VARCHAR (200),  
@vAccount VARCHAR (200)    
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @textEnglish VARCHAR(255) --missing length previously
set @textEnglish = 'hello'+ @vAccount --missing set keyword
INSERT INTO pinData([CallerID], [body], [processed]) VALUES (@callerID, @textEnglish, 0)

END
```

Comment: thank you it is working. will accept it when the system allows

Comment: will the answer be the same if the text is not english? like other langaues like chineese or arab

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change a string from

```
"hello xxx how are you"
```

to

```
"hello Mr. Smith how are you"
```

You might think about place holder replacement:

Define your string as a template:

```
DECLARE @template VARCHAR(100)='hello {Name} how are you?';
```

And then use

```
SELECT REPLACE(@template,'{Name}','Mr. Smith');
```